# change image dimensions with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize, image-size

I have a image under div id myimage. Now I want to resize it by using change. I want from select box if selected 700X7000 then image's size will be height 700px and width 700px. With out reloading the page.
Can anyone help me how can I do this?

Comment: Someone might want to audit me on this - but couldn't you create a div for the img, and set the img `max-width` to 100% and resize the div accordingly?

Comment: @melee: I think you can do that for the image directly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, to change it, you can just set the image's `width()` and `height()`:

```
$('#myimage').width(700); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$('#myimage').height(700);
```

So for you to do the drop down box, you can just set the values to be something like `100x100`, `200x200`, etc. and `split` the selected value to extract the dimensions:

```
var parts = '100x100'.split('x');
var width = parseInt(parts[0], 10); // 10 forces parseInt to use base 10
var height = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
```

Answer (score 6):

The condition is where you can say item selected.

```
if( condition ) {
   $('div#myimage img').css({'width' : '700px' , 'height' : '700px'});
}
else {
   $('div#myimage img').css({'width' : '150px' , 'height' : '150px'});
};
```

Below are ways to check to see if the box is selected:

```
// First way 
$('#checkBox').attr('checked'); 

// Second way 
$('#checkBox').is(':checked');
```

Example working:

```
if( $('#checkBox').attr('checked') ) {
   $('div#myimage img').css({'width' : '700px' , 'height' : '700px'});
}
else {
   $('div#myimage img').css({'width' : '150px' , 'height' : '150px'});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#photograph").click(function () {
                $("img").animate({

                    height: '+=5px',
                    width: '+=5px'
                });
            });
        });


        }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="photo/grass.jpg" id="photograph" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cmxevnp0/3/

Comment: Explain your answer either by words or a fiddle. Make it more human.

Answer (score 0):

Or

Function send object

```
<img onLoad="ozhpixel(this)"

function ozhpixel(imaj){
$(imaj).width(100); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$(imaj).height(50);}
```

Answer (score 0):

write

```
max-width:100%
```

in img tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.